# Failed to create a tooltip when insert a Row in Easyui Datagrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I have a Book List in my database with base64 Image.I loaded all the book information including name,ISBN,publisher etc except image in an array when open the book insertion page. So, I want the image in a tolltip when i insert the book Id in a field.I will hit a request to controller and get the image. But somehow my tooltip is not working . even I get the image data as undefined.

**here is the code for insert row :**

```js
$('#dg').datagrid('insertRow', {
index: editIndex, // index start with 0
row: {
book_id: item_id[val], bookname: item_name[val],image: item_image[val], authors: item_authors[val],
item_rate: item_localsale_rate[val], isbn: item_isbn[val],item_quantity: vr_qty, itemcost: 0, item_discount: 0, unitcost: totalItemCost
}

})
```

**Here is my code for generate tooltip:**

```js
                    $(this).datagrid('getPanel').find('tr.datagrid-row').each(function () {
var index = parseInt($(this).attr('datagrid-row-index'));

 $(this).tooltip({
zIndex: 9999999,
trackMouse: false,
position: 'top',
content: '<span style="color:#fff;"><img src=' + data.rows[index]['image'] + ' width="100" height="100"></span>'

})
                        
})
```

**And Here is the array i create for load data :
Its working fine. All data was loaded successfully**

```js
var bookList = new Array();
var item_id = new Array();
var item_name = new Array();
var item_image = new Array();
var item_isbn = new Array();
var item_authors = new Array();
var item_face_rate = new Array();
var item_wholesale_rate = new Array();
var item_localsale_rate = new Array();
var item_retailsale_rate = new Array();
var item_special_price = new Array();
var item_teacher_price = new Array();
var store_id = new Array();

var b_id = <?php echo $row->book_id; ?>;
item_id[b_id] = <?php echo $row->book_id; ?>;
item_name[b_id] = '<?php echo $row->name; ?>';
item_isbn[b_id] = '<?php echo $row->isbn; ?>';
item_image[b_id] = '';
item_authors[b_id] = '<?php echo $row->authors; ?>';
item_localsale_rate[b_id] = <?php echo $row->local_sale; ?>;
store_id[b_id] = <?php echo $row->store_id; ?>;
```

```js
 var url = '<?php echo base_url('sales/Salesinvoice/getBookCover'); ?>'+'/'+ item_id[val];
alert(url);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    var image = data.image;
    item_image[val] = image;
    alert(image);
    },
    error: function (error) {
    alert('Due Collect error');
    }
    });
```

I am little bit confused with the approach actually .What should be the approach of getting image when insert the row to datagrid.